# Makefile configuration for entire system

Tags: c++, c, makefile, clang, cs50

As we know, in the appliance when we use the command

```
make [file-name]
```

It automatically compiles with some flags:

```
-ggdb -O0 -std=c99 -Wall - Werror
```

I need to know in which directory the CS50 edited Makefile is located, because I want to configure my own Makefile for the entire system by which I can make any *.cpp* file.
When I compile c++ file with `make` it automatically compiles with `g++` but I want to compile *.cpp* file with `clang++` compiler, adding some essential flag such for `-g` for debugging `-O0` for assembly code.

I'm asking how to create a Makefile for that specific reasons, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make uses Makefiles in the current directory and [Implicit-Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules). You can modify the behavior of implicit rules by changing the variables that those explicit rules use.
For example, to change the compiler for *.cpp* files, you could set your own CXX variable, either

1. in the environment (Make uses it):

   ```
   CXX=clang++ make [file-name]
   #OR
   export CXX=clang++; make [file-name]
   ```
2. in a local Makefile:

   ```
   CXX:=clang++
   #The implicit rule, which you'll find in the link, takes care of the rest
   ```

Comment: In any case, if you're not married to your Make-based solution, I recommend you take a look at tup (https://github.com/gittup/tup), which makes building software a lot less painful.

Comment: Can I use it for java project and for complex javafx project?